# Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Here's a scenario:

Someone asked about "How to build a SQL query to get count and blah blah blah..."

His only tag is [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). I added the [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) and [count](/questions/tagged/count) tags to it.

Someone else answered with a nice SQL statement that has a "group by" statement which seems "logically inevitable".

I proceed to add a tag [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by). I did that on the basis that someone who searches for [group-by](/questions/tagged/group-by) will be able to find this post useful, just as I did. My concern is, it wasn't described at all in the question, nor was it implied, unlike [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) and [count](/questions/tagged/count).

What is the community opinion?

The scenario above is a real one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605886/counting-instances-of-unique-value-in-field). And the one who answered it nicely is Jon Skeet.

Comment: Weird, there a vote up while the view count for the post is 0. Caching at work? :P

Comment: I agree that a question should be retaged with applicable tags, byt does a group-by tag really add any benefit?  Why not a Select tag or a From tag?

Comment: @lansinwd: Only 5 tags max, and I feel that `by-group` is the essence of the context.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why not?

There are five tags to be used on a question, so use them.

When an answer gets accepted, it becomes fused (until no longer accepted) to the question.

A relevant tag to couple the question and answer together with a concept sounds perfectly valid after the fact.

Tags also help in finding related questions and possible dupes.

Comment: @random: `fused`, I like this description :)

Answer (score 11):

I'd expect that if the user had realized GROUP BY clauses were relevant to his question, he wouldn't have felt the need to ask the question at all :-)  But it looks like there's more to his question, according to his comments on Jon's answer, hence this kind of retagging might indeed do the OP a favor and help users follow up on his question.