# Should I remove tag from a question depending on the answer?

Tags: discussion, tags

My question is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que)

I just want to ask if I should remove a user's tag if it doesn't fit the question anymore.

I'll give an example.

User wanted to solve some problem with tool X, so he tagged a question with X tag. In the answer we found out that tool X is not suitable and problem can be solved with tool Y.
I know that I can add Y tag. But can I also remove X tag?
Maybe it would help other users that X tool is not suitable, but on the other hand, it could make things more transparent.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the tool X tag - after all, if other people are thinking the same thing (that the problem can be solved by Tool X) then they might read this answer and realise it's not the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

If the question was about tool x, keep that tag.

By all means, tag it with y if that's relevant, but since the question was *about* x the tag should stay.