# Should I add a tag to a question, if it's associated with the marked answer?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que)

That's not the best title but it is the best one that I can come up with in such a short field.

Here is the reason why I'm asking this question.  I just posted [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/483531/can-i-mirror-a-folders-contents-as-its-changed-in-osx) regarding folder mirroring on OSX, over at SuperUser.  I received a perfect answer, however, the answer wasn't what I expected.  Instead of mirroring, I need to create a "Symbolic Link".

At the time of my posting my question, I didn't know of the term "symbolic link" so I didn't think to tag the question as such.  However, after receiving an answer, I searched SuperUser and I saw that there are over 200 questions tagged `symbolic-link`.

Since the appropriate answer to my question applies directly to the tag but my question doesn't mention it, should I retag my question with the `symbolic-link` tag or should I leave it as it is?

I feel that I should retag the question but others may see it differently.  What are the communities thoughts?  This question may be a bit pedantic, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely add the tag.

If the problem involves some topic area, there's no reason not to tag it as such.  Doing so increases its visibility, exposing it to anyone following that tag who might well be in a position to offer an excellent answer.

Questions necessarily lack all the information about a problem, otherwise there wouldn't be anything to ask.  Answers provide most of the missing information, but tags should also be kept accurate.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it depends.  Would adding the tag exclude other possible answers that don't include the subject of the tag?  If so, then don't add it.  If the tag really represents the only viable solution, adding it should be fine.

Comment: Hmmm... Well that seems to be a counter thought to my "gut" of adding the tag.  In the case of my question, there could be a legitimate way to "mirror" the folder.  An answer could address this, while not mentioning Symbolic Links.  However, searching the `symbolic-link` tag should/could return my result and may be appropriate for a user's specific needs. :/  I'm going to keep thinking about this one...