# Should I retag a question whose answer indicates that it is mistagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que)

I am curious if a question should be edited to have a tag removed in the following situation:

The hypothetical question is tagged as a PHP/LibraryX question, in which the user is experiencing some behavior.  The answer is revealed to be an issue with RegEx/PHP and not something having to do with the library at all.

As a result, when searching for the Library and reading this answer, I'm given a false positive.  I am curious if this is worth re-tagging, since the problem isn't actually one with the knowledgebase.

Follow up bonus question.  Should questions have tags added to them based on their answers?  I'm thinking for Archival purposes.

Comment: The answer to the "bonus question" certainly matches the Possible Duplicate, but I'm more curious if I should be removing a tag which doesn't have to do with the question, once the answer is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to retag in this situation, however I advise using the *full editor* for this and adding an appropriate edit note.  I tend to use wording like

> This is not actually a $FOO-related problem

This allows future editors to see the intent behind the removal.  *Adding* tags is a *bit* more sticky, as you don't want to put words in the author's mouth.

While you have the full editor open, you should always see if there's anything else worth fixing, of course.