# Is it allowed to change tags after a question is accepted?

Tags: support, tags

Scenario : I have answered a question, and my answer has been accepted.

The tags for the question is A B C

Then, am I allowed to change the tags for the question, after my answer is accepted, to say

A B E A Y

??

Comment: I smell tag-badges :)

Comment: Related: [Should I retag a question with a tag that is based on the answer and not the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26913)

Comment: The actual question is: Why do you want to change the tags? What is wrong with them?

Comment: I saw your reply to 404 and wonder do you mean "will I be penalized for re-tagging a question which has an accepted answer?"  I've never seen any penalty when I've done it.

Comment: "I smell tag-badges :" - what is that?

Comment: See [Tag Badges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) --- you can get badges for certain numbers of upvotes within a tag.

Comment: @juergen d, off course. This is actually what I want, increase my tag-reputation so I can get badges. But it was only in one particular context, where a certain tag is objectevily better than another tag, and I vould take advantage of it. But appearently it is no problem. Thanks for answering. Did it with no penalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [tagging help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> You should re-tag questions when:
>
> - You are adding valuable information to the question by doing so
> - You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known and popular tags that are appropriate for the question.

So, absolutely. Adding in more accurate tags can never hurt. Tags are still relevant after an answer has been accepted.

As far as your example goes:

```
A B E A Y
```

I'm not sure why you would want to use the A tag twice, so I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: My real concern is, that I could be punished if I change a stackoverflow tag to my own favour.

Comment: As long as you're not considering "your own favor", and just editing the tags because the new ones are _actually_ applicable and helpful, you will have no problem, @davidkonrad.

Comment: Got it, but this was not my goal to spoil anything -actually the opposit, it would just be a personal benefit also. I wondered if the stackoverflow algorithms could "believe" it. They dont.